# jpa hibernate one to many unidirectional join on foreign key and partial pk

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

I have a one to many relationship between order and orderdetail tables.
    I use the following mapping in order entity:

```
@OneToMany
    @JoinColumns
            ({@JoinColumn(name = "ORDERIDCLIENTGUID", referencedColumnName = "CLIENTGUID", nullable = false),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "CLIENT_KEY", referencedColumnName = "CLIENT_KEY", nullable = false)
            })
    private Set<OrderDetailEntity> orderDetails = new HashSet<>();
```

The join clause that i want to perform is : ORDER.CLIENTGUID=ORDERDETAIL.ORDERIDCLIENTGUID and ORDER.CLIENT_KEY=ORDERDETAIL.CLIENT_KEY

CLIENT_KEY column is part of composite primary key. Both entities use the same embedded id:

```
@Embeddable
@Inheritance
public class BaseEntityPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="CLIENT_KEY", nullable = false)
    private long clientKey;

    @Column(name = "GUID", nullable = false)
    private long guid;

    public BaseEntityPK() {
    }
    public long getClientKey() {
        return this.clientKey;
    }
    public void setClientKey(long clientKey) {
        this.clientKey = clientKey;
    }
    public long getGuid() {
        return this.guid;
    }
    public void setGuid(long guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    public BaseEntityPK(long clientKey, long guid) {
        this.clientKey = clientKey;
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        BaseEntityPK entityPK = (BaseEntityPK) o;

        if (clientKey != entityPK.clientKey) return false;
        return guid == entityPK.guid;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (int) (clientKey ^ (clientKey >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (int) (guid ^ (guid >>> 32));
        return result;
    }
```

If I use the mappings above i get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(CLIENTGUID, CLIENT_KEY) of ...OrderDetailEntity.orderDetails referencing ...OrderEntity not mapped to a single property
```

Is there a way to map a one-to-many relationship using a foreign key and part of composite primary key?